# Insertar en tabla hija con id padre con JPA en Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Tengo un problemilla que despues de probar muchas formulas ya... me quede sin ideas y quisiera ver si alguien puede ayudarme en esto.

Estoy intentando realizar un insert de una tabla padre e hija con JPA pero no me está añadiendo el id de la tabla padre en la hija. Inserta el registro en la hija también pero el id me lo deja nulo. Estas serian las dos tablas.

La tabla Autor, solo tiene dos columnas y una relación 1/N con la tabla hija Libro indicando un HashSet:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="autor")
public class Autor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", nullable = false, insertable=false)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="nombre", columnDefinition = "varchar(127)")
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name="observaciones", columnDefinition = "varchar(255)")
    private String observaciones;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "autor", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Libro> libro = new HashSet<Libro>();

    /* Getters y Setters y Constructor */

}
```

La tabla Libro, le indico que añada una columna que será la foreign key de Autor y qu se llamará autor_id. Es este campo el que no se rellena automaticamente con el id del padre:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="libro")
public class Libro {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", nullable = false, insertable=false)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="titulo", columnDefinition = "varchar(50)")
    private String titulo;

    @Column(name="observaciones", columnDefinition = "varchar(255)")
    private String observaciones;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_libro_autor_id"), name="autor_id", referencedColumnName = "id", columnDefinition = "int")
    private Autor autor;

    /* Getters y Setters y Constructor */

}
```

El Controller, simplemente tengo un GetMapping para cargar el listado por pantalla y el Post donde creo el autor y el libro y añado este último al autor para posteriormente realizar un save en la llamada al Repository:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/autores")
public class Autores {

    @Autowired
    private AutorRepository autorRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public String findAll(Model model) {

        extracted(model);

        return "autores";

    }

    @PostMapping
    public String save(Model model) {

        Autor autor = new Autor();
        autor.setNombre("Nombre");
        autor.setObservaciones("Observaciones Autor");

        Libro libro = new Libro();
        libro.setTitulo("Titulo");
        libro.setObservaciones("Observaciones Libro");

        Set<Libro> hsLibro = new HashSet<Libro>();
        hsLibro.add(libro);

        autor.setLibro(hslibro);

        autorRepository.save(autor);

        extracted(model);

        return "autores";

    }

    private void extracted(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("autores", autorRepository.findAll());

    }

}
```

El Repository poco que añadir aquí salvo el extends JpaRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface AutorRepository extends JpaRepository<Autor, Integer> {

}
```

Esto me guarda en la tabla Autor:

```
id = 1, nombre = "Nombre", observaciones = "Observaciones Autor"
```

Y en la tabla Libro:

```
id = 1, autor_id = null, titulo = "Titulo", observaciones = "Observaciones Libro"
```

He probado de varias formas pero no consigo traspasar la el id de la tabla Autor a la foreign key.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

**SOLUCIONADO**

He modificado la clase Autor de la siguiente forma:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "autor")
public class Autor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "nombre", columnDefinition = "varchar(127)")
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name = "descripcion", columnDefinition = "varchar(255)")
    private String descripcion;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "autor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Libro> libros = new HashSet<Libro>();

    /* Getters y Setters y Constructor */

    public void addLibro(Libro libro) {
        libros.add(libro);
        libro.setAutor(this);
    }

    public void removeBook(Libro libro) {
        libros.add(libro);
        libro.setAutor(null);
    }

}
```

Y ahora he cambiado el controlador con lo siguiente

```
@PostMapping
public String save(Model model) {

    Author author = new Autor();
    author.setNombre("Nombre");
    author.setDescripcion("Descripcion Autor");

    Libro libro = new Libro();
    libro.setTitulo("Titulo");
    libro.setDescripcion("Descripcion Libro");

    autor.addLibro(libro);

    autorRepository.save(autor);

    extracted(model);

    return "autores";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que al persistir los objetos se debes asignar el Autor a la entidad Libro, el código esta bien solo debe realizar este cambio:

```
@PostMapping
public String save(Model model) {

    Autor autor = new Autor();
    autor.setNombre("Nombre");
    autor.setObservaciones("Observaciones Autor");

    Libro libro = new Libro();
    libro.setTitulo("Titulo");
    libro.setObservaciones("Observaciones Libro");
    libro.setAutor(autor);// Aquí se asigna el Autor para que la relación no sea nula

    Set<Libro> hsLibro = new HashSet<Libro>();
    hsLibro.add(libro);

    autor.setLibro(hslibro);

    autorRepository.save(autor);

    extracted(model);

    return "autores";

}
```

Otro cambio que puedes agregar es nullable = false para la relación Muchos a Uno de la entidad no permita `null` en la llave foranea libro:

```
@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_libro_autor_id"), name="autor_id", referencedColumnName = "id", columnDefinition = "int", nullable = false)
```